# I obfuscated my JavaScript. How can someone exactly decode it?

Tags: javascript

```
var _0x3424=["\x67\x65\x74","\x2F\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64","","\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65","\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72","\x73\x69\x7A\x65","\x2E\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x2D\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65","\x2E\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x2D\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x61","\x2F","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x61\x6C\x74","\x2E\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x2D\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x61\x20\x3E\x20\x69\x6D\x67","\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x66\x6F\x75\x6E\x64","\x6C\x6F\x67","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x73\x75\x70\x72\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x65\x77\x79\x6F\x72\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C","\x3A\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65","\x69\x73","\x2E\x69\x6E\x2D\x63\x61\x72\x74","\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x49\x6E\x64\x65\x78","\x70\x72\x6F\x70","\x23\x73\x69\x7A\x65","\x65\x61\x63\x68","\x23\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x20\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x69\x74\x22\x5D","\x69\x73\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74","\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x73\x75\x70\x72\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x65\x77\x79\x6F\x72\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74","\x73\x65\x6E\x64\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65","\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x73\x69\x6F\x6E"];$(function(){chrome[_0x3424[36]][_0x3424[35]]({method:_0x3424[0]},function(_0xc165x1){var _0xc165x2=false;var _0xc165x3=setInterval(function(){if(window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]][_0x3424[2]](_0x3424[1])!=-1&&_0xc165x2===false){if(_0xc165x1[_0x3424[5]]!=_0x3424[6]&&_0xc165x1[_0x3424[5]]!=undefined){var _0xc165x4=_0xc165x1[_0x3424[5]][_0x3424[7]]();var _0xc165x5=_0xc165x1[_0x3424[8]][_0x3424[7]]();for(var _0xc165x6=0;_0xc165x6<$(_0x3424[10])[_0x3424[9]]();_0xc165x6++){var _0xc165x7=$(_0x3424[12])[_0xc165x6][_0x3424[11]](_0x3424[3]);var _0xc165x8=_0xc165x7[_0x3424[14]](_0x3424[13]);_0xc165x8=_0xc165x8[_0xc165x8[_0x3424[15]]-1][_0x3424[7]]();var _0xc165x9=$(_0x3424[17])[_0xc165x6][_0x3424[11]](_0x3424[16])[_0x3424[7]]();if(_0xc165x9[_0x3424[2]](_0xc165x4)!=-1&&_0xc165x8[_0x3424[2]](_0xc165x5)!=-1&&_0xc165x2===false){_0xc165x2=true;window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]]=_0xc165x7;break ;}else {console[_0x3424[19]](_0x3424[18])};};if(_0xc165x2===false){clearInterval(_0xc165x3);window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]]=_0x3424[20];};}}});var _0xc165xa=setInterval(function(){if(window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]][_0x3424[2]](_0x3424[1])== -1){if(!$(_0x3424[23])[_0x3424[22]](_0x3424[21])){$(_0x3424[29])[_0x3424[28]](function(_0xc165x6){if($(this)[_0x3424[24]]()==_0xc165x1[_0x3424[9]]){$(_0x3424[27])[_0x3424[26]](_0x3424[25],_0xc165x6)}});$(_0x3424[31])[_0x3424[30]]();}}},100);if(_0xc165x1[_0x3424[32]]==1){var _0xc165xb=setInterval(function(){if($(_0x3424[23])[_0x3424[22]](_0x3424[21])&&window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]][_0x3424[2]](_0x3424[33])== -1){window[_0x3424[4]]=_0x3424[34];clearInterval(_0xc165xb);}},100)};})});
```

I'm wondering if this is a strong encryption, how could someone exactly decode it? Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: That is not encrypted... http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: This is not an encryption at all, it is purely some obfuscation and encoding, not overly hard to decode. Given probably less than an hour and it could all be decoded and unobfuscated. I mean just pasting "\x2F\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C" into the console in chrome, decodes it straignt away for you (i.e. "/shop/all"). So in response to your  wondering if its a strong encryption the answers is absolutely not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, how'd I do. Variable names will have changed of course, but the functionality of the code is completely readable

```
$(function () {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({ method: "get" },
        function (param1) {
            var var1 = false;
            var intHand1 = setInterval(function () {
                if (window.location.href.indexOf("/shop/all") != -1 && var1 === false) {
                    if (param1.keyword != "" && param1.keyword != undefined) {
                        var kwordlc = param1.keyword.toLowerCase();
                        var colorlc = param1.color.toLowerCase();
                        for (var i = 0; i < $(".inner-article").size() ; i++) {
                            var ahref = $(".inner-article > a")[i].getAttribute("href");
                            var ahrefsplit = ahref.split("/");
                            ahrefsplit = ahrefsplit[ahrefsplit.length - 1].toLowerCase();
                            var altlc = $(".inner-article > a > img")[i].getAttribute("alt").toLowerCase();
                            if (altlc.indexOf(kwordlc) != -1 && ahrefsplit.indexOf(colorlc) != -1 && var1 === false) {
                                var1 = true;
                                window.location.href = ahref;
                                break;
                            } else {
                                console.log("not found")
                            };
                        }; if (var1 === false) {
                            clearInterval(intHand1);
                            window.location.href = "http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all";
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
            var intHand2 = setInterval(function () {
                if (window.location.href.indexOf("/shop/all") == -1) {
                    if (!$(".in-cart").is(":visible")) {
                        $("#size option").each(function (param2) {
                            if ($(this).text() == param1.size) {
                                $("#size").prop("selectedIndex", param2)
                            }
                        }); $("[name='commit']").click();
                    }
                }
            }, 100);
            if (param1.ischeckout == 1) {
                var intHand3 = setInterval(function () {
                    if ($(".in-cart").is(":visible") && window.location.href.indexOf("shop/all") == -1) {
                        window.location = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout";
                        clearInterval(intHand3);
                    }
                }, 100)
            };
        })
});
```

Took me about 50 mins, and I got interrupted by a couple of phone calls, messages and emails.

Comment: Makes me realise how weak the obfuscation was :/ Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to recover the EXACT original code once it's obfuscated, but keep in mind that the code still needs to be understandable by the compiler/interpreter so it may be "reassembled" but most likely the original structure, classes, variable names, etc... will be lost.

My try to deobfuscate your code got me this :

```
var _0x3424 = ["\x67\x65\x74", "\x2F\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C", "\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66", "\x68\x72\x65\x66", "\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64", "", "\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65", "\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72", "\x73\x69\x7A\x65", "\x2E\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x2D\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65", "\x67\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x2E\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x2D\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x61", "\x2F", "\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x61\x6C\x74", "\x2E\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x2D\x61\x72\x74\x69\x63\x6C\x65\x20\x3E\x20\x61\x20\x3E\x20\x69\x6D\x67", "\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x66\x6F\x75\x6E\x64", "\x6C\x6F\x67", "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x73\x75\x70\x72\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x65\x77\x79\x6F\x72\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C", "\x3A\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65", "\x69\x73", "\x2E\x69\x6E\x2D\x63\x61\x72\x74", "\x74\x65\x78\x74", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x49\x6E\x64\x65\x78", "\x70\x72\x6F\x70", "\x23\x73\x69\x7A\x65", "\x65\x61\x63\x68", "\x23\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x20\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x3D\x22\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x69\x74\x22\x5D", "\x69\x73\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74", "\x73\x68\x6F\x70\x2F\x61\x6C\x6C", "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x73\x75\x70\x72\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x65\x77\x79\x6F\x72\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x6F\x75\x74", "\x73\x65\x6E\x64\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65", "\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x73\x69\x6F\x6E"];
$(function() {
    chrome[_0x3424[36]][_0x3424[35]]({
        method: _0x3424[0]
    }, function(_0xc165x1) {
        var _0xc165x2 = false;
        var _0xc165x3 = setInterval(function() {
            if (window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]][_0x3424[2]](_0x3424[1]) != -1 && _0xc165x2 === false) {
                if (_0xc165x1[_0x3424[5]] != _0x3424[6] && _0xc165x1[_0x3424[5]] != undefined) {
                    var _0xc165x4 = _0xc165x1[_0x3424[5]][_0x3424[7]]();
                    var _0xc165x5 = _0xc165x1[_0x3424[8]][_0x3424[7]]();
                    for (var _0xc165x6 = 0; _0xc165x6 < $(_0x3424[10])[_0x3424[9]](); _0xc165x6++) {
                        var _0xc165x7 = $(_0x3424[12])[_0xc165x6][_0x3424[11]](_0x3424[3]);
                        var _0xc165x8 = _0xc165x7[_0x3424[14]](_0x3424[13]);
                        _0xc165x8 = _0xc165x8[_0xc165x8[_0x3424[15]] - 1][_0x3424[7]]();
                        var _0xc165x9 = $(_0x3424[17])[_0xc165x6][_0x3424[11]](_0x3424[16])[_0x3424[7]]();
                        if (_0xc165x9[_0x3424[2]](_0xc165x4) != -1 && _0xc165x8[_0x3424[2]](_0xc165x5) != -1 && _0xc165x2 === false) {
                            _0xc165x2 = true;
                            window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]] = _0xc165x7;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            console[_0x3424[19]](_0x3424[18])
                        };
                    };
                    if (_0xc165x2 === false) {
                        clearInterval(_0xc165x3);
                        window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]] = _0x3424[20];
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        var _0xc165xa = setInterval(function() {
            if (window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]][_0x3424[2]](_0x3424[1]) == -1) {
                if (!$(_0x3424[23])[_0x3424[22]](_0x3424[21])) {
                    $(_0x3424[29])[_0x3424[28]](function(_0xc165x6) {
                        if ($(this)[_0x3424[24]]() == _0xc165x1[_0x3424[9]]) {
                            $(_0x3424[27])[_0x3424[26]](_0x3424[25], _0xc165x6)
                        }
                    });
                    $(_0x3424[31])[_0x3424[30]]();
                }
            }
        }, 100);
        if (_0xc165x1[_0x3424[32]] == 1) {
            var _0xc165xb = setInterval(function() {
                if ($(_0x3424[23])[_0x3424[22]](_0x3424[21]) && window[_0x3424[4]][_0x3424[3]][_0x3424[2]](_0x3424[33]) == -1) {
                    window[_0x3424[4]] = _0x3424[34];
                    clearInterval(_0xc165xb);
                }
            }, 100)
        };
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! :)

Comment: Not a problem, don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it was helpful ;)